# Finding the Intersection Value of a Linear Equation and a Power Function with a Negative Exponent

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, exponentiation, problem-solving

Real-life scenario, not theory, homework, etc. My math is so rusty it's basically powder at this point. No need to beat me up; I am already beating myself up for not understanding this very simple problem.

I want to find where a power function line and a linear line intersect. I know the answer is about `1.15243535589047` but I want to know how to do this with simple pen and paper (so-to-speak).

Solving for x: $-4.5657x + 265.58 = 300x^{-1}$

[image: xy scatter]

**My thought process**:

The place where the two lines intersect is where the $x$ in the linear equation equals the $x$ in the power equation. Or, the linear equation minus the power equation should equal zero.

**My attempt**:

\begin{align}
-4.5657x + 265.58 = \frac{300}{x^1}
&\implies \frac{x^1}{1} (-4.5657x + 265.58) = \frac{300}{x^1} \cdot \frac{x^1}{1} \\
&\implies x^1(-4.5657x + 265.58) = 300 \\
&\implies -4.5657x^2 + 265.58x = 300 \\
&\implies -4.5657x^2 + 265.58x -300 = 0.
\end{align}

**Now to test**:

If I plug in $1$ for $x$, I get $-38.9857$. If I plug in $1.15243535589047$, I get $0.0000425483196977439$. Since this number is very close to zero, I take that to mean $1.15$ is the $x$ value where both lines intersect (roughly). But I had to use solver or an optimizer function to figure this out.

**My question**:

**How do I take these two equations and set them up so the output will tell me that $x = 1.15$** ? I guess I'm saying I want to find where the two equations equal the same number.

Comment: The last equation you have is quadratic in $x$, which means that you are in luck!  There is a well-known closed-form solution to such equations, provided by the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solve the quadratic equation by the formula
$$x_{1,2}=-\frac{b}{2a}\pm\frac{1}{2a}\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$$
with your values i get
$$x\approx 1.15244$$
$$x\approx 57.0161$$

Comment: I can't believe I was asking about the quadratic formula without even knowing it. I guess a perfect example of why they teach us this in school but I didn't realize when to apply it. Thank you!

Comment: ok nice that your Problem is solved now, have a nice evening!

Answer (score 1):

$x$ is definitely non-zero, this means your steps in setting up the quadratic is correct, which is multiplying both sides by $x$.
You don't really have to plug in values to test and you can instead use the quadratic formula for solving questions in the form \begin{align}ax^2+bx+c=0\end{align}
The formula is given as:
\begin{align}\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\end{align}
Plugging in the values for a, b, c and you should get:
$x=57.016082234325$ and 
$x=1.1524351890714$